# User input integer list

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, int

I am trying to create a piece of code that allows me to ask the user to enter 5 numbers at once that will be stored into a list. For instance the code would would be ran and something like this would appear in the shell

```
Please enter five numbers separated by a single space only:
```

To which the user could reply like this

```
 1 2 3 4 5
```

And then the numbers 1 2 3 4 5 would be stored into a list as integer values that could be called on later in the program.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best way of doing this, is probably going to be a list comprehension.

```
user_input = raw_input("Please enter five numbers separated by a single space only: ")
input_numbers = [int(i) for i in user_input.split(' ') if i.isdigit()]
```

This will split the user's input at the spaces, and create an integer list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
my_list = input("Please enter five numbers separated by a single space only")
my_list = my_list.split(' ')
```

Comment: Now how do you turn the numbers you input into integers?

Comment: Both mine and Daniel's answer will return a list of integers rather than a list of integer *strings*. @FCBHokie

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved very easily by using the `raw_input()` function and then convert them to a list of string using `split()` and `map()`

```
num = map(int,raw_input("enter five numbers separated by a single space only" ).split())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use regular expressions as the user may also enter non-integer values as well:

```
nums = [int(a) for a in re.findall(r'\d+', raw_input('Enter five integers: '))]
nums = nums if len(nums) <= 5 else nums[:5] # cut off the numbers to hold five
```

Comment: You don't *need* to - if the user enters non-integers why *shouldn't* it fail?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a subtle way to take user input into a list:

```
l=list()
while len(l) < 5: # any range
    test=input()
    i=int(test)
    l.append(i)

print(l)
```

It should be easy enough to understand. Any range range can be applied to the `while` loop, and simply request a number, one at a time.